# Setting up my Samsung SA550 screen

Tags: display, setup

I just bought a new Samsung PC monitor but I am having trouble setting it up properly. I have run the auto-setup several times but I am still not satisfied with the quality.

I have connected two screens where one shows some of the bright colours better than the new screen. I took a picture of this with my iPhone to compare the two:

[image: http://gyazo.com/280a164fa9c415df54e00e8ef3338c7b]

As you can see the one on the left (my old screen) has a bit of a pattern between each row whereas the one on the right (my new screen) seems to be all white.

Can anyone please tell me what setting I have to play around with to get this working properly?

Comment: Samsung is defect. I had two LCD and when i knock on top it shows broken color like you have. I returned both LCD as defect and asked money back but they told to get another one. Something is wrong in there production.

Comment: Nah, it's not defect, it's probably just the quality of the image taken with my iPhone. It's the fact that the really bright colours all seems to be shown as white. If I adjust the light to be the darkest setting, I can see the pattern, and it is also possible to se it now but only vague.